# build a new url with a string

Tags: javascript, angular

I get a string that is dynamic depending on the environment :

`const dynamicString = environnement-dev.com`

and I would transform this string into an url automatically starting with `https: //`

I am currently using this method :

```
 const dynamicString = environnement-dev.com;
 const url = 'https://'+ dynamicString
```

that does the job, but I would like to know if there is another more conventional method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [URL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) this will throw an error if the url does not conform to the current format

```
 const dynamicString = 'environnement-dev.com';
 const url = new URL(`https://${dynamicString}`);
```

And since you receive an object, with `url.href` you can get the full url

Answer (score 1):

```js
const dynamicString = 'environnement-dev.com';
const getUrl = (addres) => `https://${addres}`
console.log(getUrl(dynamicString))
```